# ActiveRecord destroy method - wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 3 tables and 3 models:

Car.rb

```
  has_many :cars_domains, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :domains, :through => :cars_domains
```

Domain.rb

```
has_many :cars_domains
has_many :cars, :through => :cars_domains
```

and cars_domain.rb

```
class CarsDomain < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :domain

  attr_accessible :car_id, :domain_id
end

class CreateCarsDomains < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :cars_domains, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :car, :domain
      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :cars_domains, [:car_id, :domain_id]
  end
end
```

One car can be in some domains.
When I create a car and tied to a domain, then all is well.

But when I try destroy from cars_domains table, I have errors:

```
CarsDomain.where(:car_id => 2, :domain_id => 1).destroy
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

Or

```
 CarsDomain.where(:car_id => 2, :domain_id => 1).destroy_all

  CarsDomain Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "cars_domains".* FROM "cars_domains" WHERE "cars_domains"."car_id" = 2 AND "cars_do
mains"."domain_id" = 1

   (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
Could not log "sql.active_record" event. NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "cars_domains" WHERE "cars_domains"."" = $1
                                                        ^
: DELETE FROM "cars_domains" WHERE "cars_domains"."" = $1
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_
adapter.rb:1062:in `prepare'
```

What's wrong?

UPD:

```
CarsDomain.destroy_all(:car_id => 2, :domain_id => 1)
```

CarsDomain Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "cars_domains".* FROM "cars_domains" WHERE "cars_domains"."car_id" = 2 AND "cars_do
mains"."domain_id" = 1
   (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
Could not log "sql.active_record" event. NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """"
LINE 1: DELETE FROM "cars_domains" WHERE "cars_domains"."" = $1
                                                        ^
: DELETE FROM "cars_domains" WHERE "cars_domains"."" = $1

UPD 2

I think that problem in ID ---- create_table :cars_domains, :id => false. Because Destroy method need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in : 
    create_table :cars_domains, :id => false do |t|

Correct variant is:
     create_table :cars_domains do |t|

And CarsDomain.where(:car_id => params[:car_id], :domain_id => params[:domain_id]).destroy_all

Answer (score 5):

Because you got more entries, and it belongs to CarsDomain. CarsDomain#destroy expects an id, so that's why you got this message. Use `destory_all` with condition!

`CarsDomain.destroy_all(:car_id => 2, :domain_id => 1)`

Comment: CarsDomain.destroy_all(:car_id => 2, :domain_id => 1)

Answer (score 4):

You're working on a collection, so use `destroy_all`.

[See doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all).

Answer (score 3):

In your Car model (car.rb) you have the dependent set to `:delete_all`, when it should be `:destroy`, meaning `has_many :cars_domains, :dependent => :destroy`

If your domain is also dependent you need to add `:dependent => :destroy` to your domain model as well.